# Conditionally check Type and return true or false

Tags: typescript

```js
//type A; // Defined outside of my code
//type B extends A; // defined outside of my code

interface Config<T> = {
   endpoint: 'my/path'
   ...properties same for both A and B
}

const isTypeB = ( config: Config<T> ): boolean => {

 // if T extends B
 return true;

 // else if (T only extends A)
 return false;

}
```

When I call `isTypeB` how can I check if `T` extends a specific type and return a `true` or `false` based on this.

Comment: TypeScript types are only present at compile time, not at runtime, so a function which checks for TS types at runtime is not possible.

Comment: Either this is impossible because the information you need is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) before your code runs, or you're asking us to help you write a runtime check in which case this isn't a [mre] because we need definitions of `A`, `B`, and whatever depends on `T` inside `Config<T>`.  Please [edit] to clarify and let us know how to proceed.